# imaplib wrongly adding `=` and `3D` characters to url text from email

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imaplib

Here I'm using `imapblib` and `email` to retrieve a certain email message based on certain criteria (i.e. who it's from and the subject).

```
import imaplib
import email

FROM_EMAIL  = "##########@gmail.com"
FROM_PWD    = "##########"
SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
mail.select("INBOX")
result, data2 = mail.search(None,'(FROM "####" SUBJECT "####")')
ids = data2[0]
id_list = ids.split()
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
result, email_data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")

raw_email = email_data[0][1]
raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
```

In the email, using gmail on my desktop, there is a link that appears like this (please note, the # character represents sensitive information):

```
# This is how the link is supposed to appear
https://inreach.garmin.com/textmessage/txtmsg?extId=e3e7d4c2-fab4-43ad-93de-f9dedca8280#####=##########%40gmail.com
```

When printing the email text as python has retrieved it, I get this bad link:

```
email_text = list(email_message.walk())[1].get_payload()
print(email_text) # Note(I am not printing the whole email for privacy reasons)

# The link as python has retrieved it appears like this:

https://inreach.garmin.com/textmessage/txtmsg?extId=3De3e7d4c2-fab4-43ad-93=de-f9dedca8280#####=3D##########%40gmail.com
```

Python is somehow adding an `=` character between `93` and `de` and it is also adding several `3D` characters.

What is python doing?  Ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). It's one way of encoding arbitrary bytes into ASCII text for transmission through e.g. email. Among the consequences of this encoding are the following:

- Each `'='` character in your message gets encoded into `'=3D'` (because 0x3d is the character code for `'='`).
- Lines are wrapped at 76 characters by inserting the sequence `'=\n'` (basically an escaped newline which the decoder will strip out). I bet one of these newlines got inserted in the middle of your link.

You can convert the encoded text back to the original bytes using the [`quopri` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) from the standard library. Some parts of Python's [email handling library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) may also do this for you.